# GPathResult ..presence or absence of a node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, groovy, gpath

My GPathResult can have a name node in one of the 3 ways

1) name node is present and has a value
ex: John

2) name node exists, but has no value in it.

3) No name node exists at all.

In Groovy code, how do i differenciate between the above 3 cases using my Gpathresult. Do I use something like gPathResult. value()!=null ?

Pesudo code:

```
if(name node is present and has a value){
do this
}

if(name node exists, but has no value in it){
do this
}

if( No name node exists at all){
do this
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to test for `size()`.
To stay with the example of Olivier, just fixed so that `GPathResult` is used and that it works with both, `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser` here the code:

```
def xml="<a><b>yes</b><c></c></a>"
def gpath = new XmlSlurper().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())) 
["b", "c", "d" ].each() {
    println it
    if (gpath[it].size()) {
        println "  exists"
        println gpath[it].text() ? "  has value" : "   doesn't have a value"
    } else {
        println "  does not exist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Test if gpath result is null to check presence, and use `.text()` method for the element value (empty string if no value).
Here's an example:

```
def xml="<a><b>yes</b><c></c></a>"
def gpath = new XmlParser().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())) 
["b", "c", "d" ].each() {
    println it
    if (gpath[it]) {
        println "  exists"
        println gpath[it].text() ? "  has value" : "   doesn't have a value"
    } else {
        println "  does not exist"
    }
}
```

(the `gpath[it]` notation is because of the variable replacement, if you look for a specific element such as `b` then you can use `gpath.b`)

Comment: XmlParser does not return a `GPathResult` but a `Node`. Those two behave differently in the scope of this question, as your else path will NEVER be triggered.

Comment: Vampire is correct, [here](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) is a document with some info about `XmlParser` and `Node` as opposed to `XmlSlurper` and `GPathResult`.